# neural network classification in matlab

Tags: neural-network

My input data is an 101*22 array(101 samples and 22 features).

These data(101) should be divided into *3 groups*(*L1*, *L2* and *L3*).

I want to use mat lab neural network as classifier.

What will be target array?
What other classifier you recommend?
Thanks

Comment: So you have the feature matrix X let's say that is 101*22. The target should be the classes/labels L1,L2,L3. For example, if the sample is in L1 group then assign the number 0 to it. If the sample is in L2 group then assign the number 1 to it and if the sample is in L3 group then assign the number 2 to it.  Then you can perform a classification. Search for multi class classification.

Comment: hi, using nprtool in matlab,i upload the data but it does not upload the target array.how I can do that?

Comment: you can write the data to a csv file I think. I am not familiar with nprtool but you can write a .mat file to a .csv file [see here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/195151-how-to-convert-a-mat-file-into-a-csv-file)

Comment: thanks sera,but its not working

Comment: could anyone one helps me with nprtool in matlab?

Comment: i will Check the nprtool and let you know

Answer (score 0):

The target data should be the classes of the Input data. In your case you have 3 classes. You can use a binary coding.

More details about the input and target data can be found here at the end of the page [see here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotconfusion.html)

Other resources:

[first](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html)

A simple example can be the following:

```
#this is the INPUT data that you have
X=randint(101,22,[0 10]);

#this is the TARGET data
y =randint(3,22,[0 1]);

#define hidden layer size
hiddenLayerSize = 10;

#create the neural net
my_net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

#run it
[my_net,tr] = trainrp(my_net,X,y);
```

Then you should see something like the following:

[image]

Then explore this windows.

E.g. select confusion

[image]